# ES6 : Object restructuration for mailchimp api

Tags: object, ecmascript-6

I want to construct a object base on an array and another object.

The goal is to send to mailchimp api my users interests, for that, I've got :

```
//Array of skills for one user    
const skillsUser1 = ["SKILL1", "SKILL3"]

//List of all my skills match to mailchimp interest group
const skillsMailchimpId = {
  'SKILL1': 'list_id_1',
  'SKILL2': 'list_id_2',
  'SKILL3': 'list_id_3',
}

//Mapping of user skill to all skills
const outputSkills = skillsUser1.map((skill) => skillsMailchimpId[skill]);
console.log(outputSkills);
```

The problem is after, outputSkill get me an array :

```
["ID1", "ID3"]
```

But what the [mailchimp api need](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#edit-patch_lists_list_id_members_subscriber_hash), and so what I need : :

```
{ "list_id_1": true,
  "list_id_2": false, //or empty
  "list_id_3" : true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way would be this (see comments in code for explanation):

```js
// Array of skills for one user    
const skillsUser1 = ["SKILL1", "SKILL3"]

// List of all my skills match to mailchimp interest group
const skillsMailchimpId = {
  'SKILL1': 'list_id_1',
  'SKILL2': 'list_id_2',
  'SKILL3': 'list_id_3',
}

// Create an output object
const outputSkills = {};

// Use `Object.entries` to transform `skillsMailchimpId` to array
Object.entries(skillsMailchimpId)
  // Use `.forEach` to add properties to `outputSkills`
  .forEach(keyValuePair => {
    const [key, val] = keyValuePair;
    outputSkills[val] = skillsUser1.includes(key);
  });

console.log(outputSkills);
```

The basic idea is to loop over `skillsMailchimpId` instead of `skillsUser`.

But that is not very dynamic. For your production code, you probably want to refactor it to be more flexible.

```js
// Array of skills for one user    
const skillsUser1 = ["SKILL1", "SKILL3"]

// List of all my skills match to mailchimp interest group
const skillsMailchimpId = {
  'SKILL1': 'list_id_1',
  'SKILL2': 'list_id_2',
  'SKILL3': 'list_id_3',
}

// Use `Object.entries` to transform `skillsMailchimpId` to array
const skillsMailchimpIdEntries = Object.entries(skillsMailchimpId);

const parseUserSkills = userSkills => {
  // Create an output object
  const outputSkills = {};
  
  // Use `.forEach` to add properties to `outputSkills`
  skillsMailchimpIdEntries.forEach(([key, val]) => {
    outputSkills[val] = userSkills.includes(key);
  });
  
  return outputSkills;
}

// Now you can use the function with any user
console.log(parseUserSkills(skillsUser1));
```

Comment: Yes, It will maybe easier to use an object like this :
const skillsMailchimpIds = [
  {skillId : 'SKILL1', id : 'ID_1'},
  {skillId : 'SKILL2', id : 'ID_2'}
]

And the use .filter and .map ?

Comment: I tried :
const outSkill = (skillUser1, skillsMailchimpIds)  => {
  return skillsMailchimpIds.filter((skillsMailchimpId) => {
    return skillsMailchimpId.skillId;
    }
  )
}

Comment: @Kaherdin you don't have to manipulate your `skillsMailchimpId`. Just use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries). What I meant by refactoring is just wrapping the operations in a function or something like that. Your attempt, while not incorrect, is making it way more complicated than it should.